# Keeping the text size the same when zooming in and out

Tags: python, text, svg, zooming

I have created svg file with line elements, and middle point of every line represents coordinate for line's name (svg text element). What is the best way to keep the size of those text elements when zooming in and out, but their place needs to be always at the middle of the lines?

In my python GUI, I  zoom svg like this:

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):
    factor = 1 + 0.1 * event.delta() / 120.0
    self.scale(factor, factor)
    event.accept()
```

where `self` is `QtGui.QGraphicsView`  in which I draw my svg like this:

```
self.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
self.scene().addItem(QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem(QtCore.QFile(pathToMySVG).fileName()))
```